# Cannot invoke format(Date) on the primitive type void

Tags: java

In the jasper Report I am trying the following

`new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).format( new Date(1483337940000L));`

in the text field Expression.

But I am getting the error

> Cannot invoke format(Date) on the primitive type void

Is not it  the same as the following code in java?

```
1483337940000L is 02.01.2107 07:19

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String test  = sdf.format(new Date(1483337940000L)); // Here I am getting 06:19

String test2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).format( new Date(1483337940000L)); // Here I am getting the error Cannot invoke format(Date) on the primitive type void
```

Comment: setTimeZone does not return a value. It's a void method

Comment: The idiom `obj.operation1().operation2().operation3()` only works if each of the operations is defined as returning the object it was invoked on. This is not how this operation is defined, and therefore you can't use this "chained commands" idiom.

Comment: I guess not else will be happening here; so please consider accepting at some point ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The method [setTimeZone()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) comes from the DateFormat class; and doesn't return a value; as it is **void**!

And when you  write

```
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).format(new Date(1483337940000L));
```

you try to invoke `format()` on the result of setTimeZone().

But as that method doesn't have a result; that must fail!

The real take-away here: don't **assume** what a method is doing. Yes, some APIs are written to allow for "fluent calls", by returning the object on which methods are called; but not all of them! So, when in doubt: check the javadoc. First.